# How to add text dynamic in defaultValue property with TextField from MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to add `Edited` text after the message if the `edit` value is `true`.

How can I do that with `TextField` component from MUI?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(true);

  const comment = "This is a comment from user.";
  const message = `${comment} ${edit ? "Edited" : null}`;

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        defaultValue={message}
        style={{ width: "300px" }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Currently, I'm seeing `This is a comment from user. Edited` text when the `edit` is `true` and `This is a comment from user. null` text when the `edit` is `false`.

I just want to display `Edited` and don't need to show `null`.

#### Attempts

I tired

```
const message = `${comment} ${edit && "Edited"}`;
```

but this shows `This is a comment from user. false` text in the text input.

Comment: `${edit ? "Edited" : ""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null is being transformed into a string. Try instead:

const message = `${comment} ${edit ? "Edited" :""}`;